# Is any closed and bounded subset of a reflexive Banach space compact in the weak topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

It seems to me that Alaoglu's theorem implies that any closed and bounded subset of a reflexive Banach space is compact in the weak topology. Is convexity of the set also needed?

Comment: Take the unit sphere of $\ell_2$. $0$ is in its weak closure; so, it's not weakly closed.

Comment: @David Thank you. It'd be great if you could please spot the flaw in my argument?: Any closed ball in $X^{*}$ is weak* compact by Alaoglu's theorem. By reflexivity, any closed and bounded set in $X=X^{**}$ is therefore compact in the weak* topology on $X^{**}$, hence compact in the weak topology on $X^{**}$, hence compact in the weak topology on $X$.

Comment: Any weak* closed and norm bounded set is weak* compact. Norm closed bounded sets need not be weak* closed.

Comment: @David Thanks again! I need the fact that a norm-closed and convex set is weakly closed...